# How to recode multiple variables at once with an else=copy option depending on another variables condition in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, purrr, recode

Let's see an example.

```
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
```

From this dataset I want to recode all variables whose name contains `cop` (so I could use the tidyselect `contains`) as follows. For males (`e16sex==1`) `NA` into `999` and `else=copy` (as I could do with `sjmisc::rec(..., rec = "NA=999; else=copy"`); for females (`e16sex==2`) keep them intact.

I tried through `dplyr` (and `sjmisc`) the next naive test:

```
mutate_at(efc, vars(contains("cop")), list(~if_else(e16sex == 1, rec(., rec="NA=999; else=copy"),.)))
```

but, as it is understandable, `if_else` does not process the second dot `.` as if it was the original `contains("cop")`-variables for the rows with `e16sex != 1`.

I am looking for a function (or composite) returning a data frame with the recoding specified (so, please, avoid `for`). I could not try with `data.table` because I do not know yet the language, but all effective (and efficient) solutions are welcome. Maybe could it be done with `purrr`?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

The naive test above works. I hadn't tried it with this example but with `iris` dataset, and with `Species` variable instead of `cop`variables. As `Species` is factor, trying to change some of its levels by a new one produce `NA`'s, thence my confusion.

Comment: Try `case_when` for these more complex if-else statements.

Comment: I know `case_when` but I don't see how can I solve with it the problem above with `if_else`, that is, how to say it to keep multiple variables identically.?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood this question.

Comment: can you provide some sample data so that we dont have install the package? maybe u r looking for `cols <- grep("cop", names(efc), value=TRUE); setDT(efc)[e16sec==1L, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) fcoalesce(x, 999L)), .SDcols=cols]`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but you could use a for loop for this:

```
for(x in grep( "cop",names(efc))) { 
   efc[!is.na(efc$e16sex) & efc$e16sex==1 & is.na(efc[,x]),x] <- 999 
   }
```